# The Witcher 3 can't sprint

Tags: pc, the-witcher-3

I can't run fast or sprint. What does that mean?
I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. Help me guys.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Have you changed the key binds

Comment: That screenshot you posted seems to imply you already know what's wrong.

Answer (score 11):

You're carrying too much. The red icon below your health bar indicates that you're overencumbered.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely an error in your key binds, just check the buttons. If not, check that you are not carrying too much.